# How to hide a specific unmounted volume

Tags: debian, volume

I am using Debian 9 with xfce and I would like to hide an unmounted volume in the Desktop.
I tried to install udisk; however, I ran into a lot of problems. 
Does anyone know an easy way to hide an unmounted volume?

Comment: Could you edit your post to include what steps you have taken so far what errors you have encountered? Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This worked for me:

```
# cat /etc/udev/rules.d/99-hide-partitions.rules
KERNEL=="sda*", ENV{UDISKS_IGNORE}="1"
```

You should run `udevadm control --reload` (as root) after modifying any udev rules, and log out and in to your desktop environment.

Comment: Unfortunately still not working for me

Comment: that's curious. I've copy-pasted it from a (vanilla) debian 9 machine with xfce, no less.

Comment: It worked after restarting the computer